# async javascript library call from C code finishes too late

Tags: javascript, c, asynchronous, promise, emscripten

I am using emscripten to compile a C program which makes use of a JavaScript library I have written, and I'm linking them together with the `--js-library` flag. My C code calls a function in the library which has a `Promise` in it, and in the callback I want it to write the given result to some memory which has been passed into the JS function from the C caller. Here is an example (I omitted the error-catching `catch` part of the Promise for brevity):

lib.js

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  compute_js: function(input, out_buf) {
    do_promise_computation(
      input
    ).then(function(result){
       Module.print("Promise Returned fully");
       for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         var num = result[i]
         {{{makeSetValue('out_buf+(i*4)', 0, 'num', 'i32')}}}
       }
  });
}
```

program.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

extern void compute_js(int32_t, int64_t*);

int main() {
  int32_t input = 1234;
  int64_t out_buf[4];
  int64_t* out_ptr = (int64_t*)(&out_buf);
  printf("Calling Javascript\n");
  compute_js(input, out_ptr);
  printf("%lld\n", out_buf[0]);
  printf("%lld\n", out_buf[1]);
}
```

In other functions, without Promises, that I've written for the library, I have been able to successfully write the data to the buffer given from the C code, but this time, the output comes back as follows:

```
Calling Javascript
0
0
Promise Returned fully
```

But I want to be able to wait for the result from the Promise and then write it into the C code, so that `Promise Returned Fully` comes before the `printf` statements in the C code which are after the JavaScript call. Is there a way to do this with emscripten?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with emscripten, I'm afraid, but a friend of mine who is asked if you can use semaphore, it should solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know this environment, but can you have your Javascript call a callback function in your C code from the `.then()` handler?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ASYNCIFY_FUNCTIONS` and `_emscripten_async_resume`.

https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/asyncify.html

Comment: I tried this, but even after doing all that was said, I would get errors. Namely, I am not sure where to call `_emscripten_async_resume()`. If I call it in C, it says that it is an 'implicit declaration' of a function and not allowed. If I call it in JS, I am told `ReferenceError: ___async is not defined`. And I have been compiling my code with `-s ASYNCIFy=1 -s ASINCIFY_FUNCTIONS=['compute_js_helper']` (helper function is a C function which wraps the JS function call).